# python dictionary function get() return None

Tags: python

My program:

```
best = {0: 0, '24': 3, '9': 1, '11': 1}
for i in best:
        print best.get(str(best))
```

Any ideasy why it's return always none. I am giving key to get arg so all should work good.

Comment: 1. `best` is the dictionary, not the key. 2. Why use `.get`? 3. And why use `str`?! Just use `best[i]`, or iterate over `best.values()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You’re getting `str(best)` each time, which is not a key in your dictionary. It should look like this instead:

```
best = {0: 0, '24': 3, '9': 1, '11': 1}
for i in best:
    print best.get(str(i))
```

However since `i` is *always* a key in `best` you can just use `best[i]`:

```
for i in best:
    print best[i]
```

Note that if all you want are the dictionary values you can use `best.values()`:

```
for value in best.values():
    print value
```

If you want both the key and the value you can use `.items()`:

```
for key, value in best.items():
    print key, value
```

Comment: Not all keys are string so calling `str(i)` causes mismatches. Just call `best[i]`

Comment: @ozgur Yes that’s probably why OP used `.get()` instead of `[]`. I’m assuming this is a simple code example and their real use-case is more complicated than that. Or maybe they want to understand how `.get()` works.